# How to initiate cooperation requests in Death Stranding on PC?

Tags: death-stranding

I've done a fair bit of googling and the closest thing to an answer I found involves the PS4: select the structure you'd like other players to help you build on the map and press triangle.

Great... What is the keybinding on PC? The UI doesn't even provide a hint about which key it is. And yes, I've leveled porting enough to allow for two requests at the same time but having tried every single key I just can't figure out how to mark a structure I need help building.

It'll take forever to rebuild the roads on my own lonesome.

Answer (score 2):

Open the map (<kbd>Tab</kbd>), select a structure on the map. Press <kbd>F</kbd> to request an upgrade.

[image]